# How to implement one to many video broadcast with peerjs

Tags: webrtc, peerjs

is it possible to implement one-to-many video broadcast with peerjs or is their any other better JavaScript library that I can use if peerjs can't do it

Answer (score 1):

Peerjs is just a wrapper for the native `RTCPeerconnection` in the browser. And there are also others like `simple-peer` for example.

Though you can implement one-to-many broadcasting with all of them.

note: you can't expect to be able to broadcast audio+video to a big amount of people at the same time that way (like 50 for example).

Comment: What if i want to broadcast to more than 50 users, How can i do that

Comment: You would need an SFU like [mediasoup](https://mediasoup.org)

Comment: what are we supposed to pass as MediaStream while calling if we don't want our stream to be shares?.

Comment: @CircuitPlanet what do you mean?

Comment: I want to make a one way live video streaming app in which the admin will be starting a socket room and after that the viewers will be joining the room.
I want to share the admin's stream but not the viewer's stream.
I tried this but could not find the right solution using peerjs.

It seems that we can not start a call without a stream. but keeping in mind that we can answer the call without the stream i am using this the opposite way for now.